# Add SVG in Angular2 all at once

Tags: angular, svg, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating chrome extension with angular2. I have img folder with few SVG files. Is there any way to import all svg files at once and use them separately in any html template?

For example in c# application I can import in _layout.cshtml like this:

```
@Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Enviroment.WebRootPath + "/img/img.svg"))
```

which generates img.svg from all svg files and then I can use it like this:

```
<svg class="icon" style="fill: red;"><use xlink:href="#grid" /></svg>
```

So is there a way to do this i chrome extension angular2 app?

BTW I'm using webpack if this helps...

Comment: @wOxxOm example would be really nice!

Comment: Not clear what exactly is your question here. Are you asking how to list files from a Chrome extension (which is what wOxxOm answered), or are you asking how to use webpack to produce a combined SVG file? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

To read an extension package directory at runtime use chrome.runtime.[getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry):

```
function readFiles(path, extension) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(root => {
            const rootLen = root.fullPath.length;
            root.getDirectory(path.replace(/^\//, ''), {create: false}, dir => {
                dir.createReader().readEntries(entries => {
                    Promise.all(entries
                        .filter(e => e.isFile && e.name.endsWith(extension))
                        .map(e => {
                            const url = chrome.runtime.getURL(e.fullPath.substr(rootLen));
                            return fetch(url)
                                .then(r => r.text())
                                .then(text => ({text, name: e.name}));
                        })
                    ).then(resolve);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
readFiles('/img', '.svg').then(svgs => {
    svgs.forEach(svg => {
        // svg.name is the file name
        // svg.text is the file contents
        ................
    });
});
```

or

```
readFiles('/img', '.svg').then(svgs => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', svgs.map(svg => svg.text).join(''));
});
```